# How is the SCM Command generated by Jenkins

Tags: mercurial, jenkins

I have mercurial repository, and by providing the URL to Jenkins, i get the following in stdout:

```
Started by an SCM change
[workspace] $ hg incoming --quiet --bundle hg.bundle --template "{desc|xmlescape}{file_adds|stringify|xmlescape}{file_dels|stringify|xmlescape}{files|stringify|xmlescape}{parents}\n" --rev default
[workspace] $ hg unbundle hg.bundle
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
(run 'hg update' to get a working copy)
[workspace] $ hg update --clean --rev default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[workspace] $ hg log --rev . --template {node}
No emails were triggered.
```

Question is HOW are these commands generated and can they be modified ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those commands are part of the [Mercurial Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin), with the [source code available at GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin).

You can find the incoming command used in the [`hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/mercurial/MercurialSCM.java) class in the [`update()` method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/mercurial/MercurialSCM.java#L428).

```
os.write("<changesets>\n".getBytes());
ArgumentListBuilder args = findHgExe(build, listener, false);
args.add(forest ? "fincoming" : "incoming", "--quiet");
if (!forest) {
    args.add("--bundle", "hg.bundle");
}

args.add("--template", MercurialChangeSet.CHANGELOG_TEMPLATE);

args.add("--rev", getBranch(env));
```